# Поисковик принимает страницу за дубликат

Tags: seo

Есть небольшой интернет-магазин, гугл считает многие страницы с описанием товара дубликатами, хотя это разные товары, может есть несколько названий товаров, которые совпадают, не считая хедера и футера. Как с этим бороться? Каноническую страницу не хочется делать, т.к. это отдельные товары.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждая веб-страница должна иметь уникальное содержание. Если создать 100 веб-страниц с дублированным содержанием, то в лучшем случае веб-сайт получит запрет для показа в результатах поиска. Дублированное содержание может иметь каннибализацию ключевых слов - дублированное содержание будет конкурировать и делить сок между собой.

Если ваши веб-страницы описывают разный товар, то и содержание веб-страниц должно быть разное. Например, если одна веб-страница предлагает автомобиль Вольво V-90, а другая веб-страница предлагает Вольво XC-60, то, соответственно и содержание этих веб-страниц имеют различный текст описания. Однако если веб-мастер лениться создавать уникальное содержание, то он может копировать на все свои веб-страницы с автомобилями текст не имеющий характеристик различных моделей, например "Лучшая автомашина Вольво за низкую цену" или что-то подобное. Если пользователь в поиске задаст вопрос о покупке автомобиля Вольво, то боты поисковиков будут искать на веб-страницах информацию которая будет наиболее точно соответствовать запросу. Так как эти гипотетические веб-страницы будут иметь дублированное содержание и каннибализацию ключевых слов, то боты не смогут определить какая именно веб-страница подходит наилучшим образом, отбросят эти веб-страницы и перейдут к другим веб-сайтам.

Comment: Спасибо. Понял, нужно создать уникальное описание для каждого товара